# Video module javascript stripping out other source tags

Tags: 7, files

I'm using the Video module and Zencoder to transcode my uploaded videos into 5 different formats. The HTML generated is great:

```
<video id="video-3144-video" data-setup="{}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="502" height="282" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="http://blah.rackcdn.com/videos/thumbnails/3144/10bii Test Image.png">
  <source src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/m3u8/663b02ec652f3053bff1d133d85f228f.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" />
  <source src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/myvideo_webm_1357326043.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/myvideo_flv_1357326044.flv" type="video/flv" />
  <source src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/myvideo_mp4_1357326045.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/myvideo_ogv_1357326045.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

However, something on the Javascript side is altering the video tag, stripping out all of the source tags and converting it to this:

```
<video id="video-3144-video_html5_api" data-setup="{}" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" src="http://blah.rackcdn.com/myvideo_webm_1357326043.webm"></video>
```

However, I would like the DOM to keep all of those `<source>` tags because I'd like to have some of my own Javascript use the URLs.

Is there some configuration change I can make or some code change I can make that will let the Video.js do its work but still leave the source tags intact?